# EntityTypeBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Navigation'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

How do I resolve this EntityTypeBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Navigation'?

Just added migration.

Project: Class Library .Net statndard 2.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("ExpenseManager.DAL.Entities.Ex_paymentretirement", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("ExpenseManager.DAL.Entities.Ex_requisitionpayment", "Ex_requisitionpayment")
                    .WithOne("Ex_paymentretirement")
                    .HasForeignKey("ExpenseManager.DAL.Entities.Ex_paymentretirement", "RequisitionPaymentId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Navigation("Ex_requisitionpayment");//here*****
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("ExpenseManager.DAL.Entities.Ex_requisitiondetails", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("ExpenseManager.DAL.Entities.Ex_classificationsetup", "Ex_classificationsetup")
                    .WithMany("Ex_requisitiondetails")
                    .HasForeignKey("ClassificationsetupId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasOne("ExpenseManager.DAL.Entities.Ex_requisitionote", "ex_Requisitionote")
                    .WithMany("Ex_requisitiondetails")
                    .HasForeignKey("RequisitionId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Navigation("Ex_classificationsetup");//here*****

                b.Navigation("ex_Requisitionote");//here*****
            });
```

Comment: `Navigation` if a feature of EF Core 5

Comment: if I understood what you mean by history    I have done this before adding migration   to OnModelCreating method from my datacontext class onModelmodelBuilder.Entity<Ex_requisitionote>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Ex_requisitionpayment)
                .WithOne(b => b.Ex_requisitionote)
                .HasForeignKey<Ex_requisitionpayment>(b => b.RequisitionId);

Comment: I tried doing one to one entity mapping using fluent API

Comment: Oh Thanks so much, I've just downgraded

Answer (score 2):

Method `Navigation` was added in .NET 5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.navigation?view=efcore-5.0

In EFCore 5 `NavigationBuilder` is for configuring relation properties, like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .HasMany(b => b.Posts)
    .WithOne();

modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .Navigation(b => b.Posts)
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
```

It contains also methods `HasField`, `HasAnnotation`, `IsRequired`.

To fix an issue you need to downgrade to EFCore 3.1 and regenerate migrations

Comment: i've just tried removing the line, this is what I get Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.Builders.OperationBuilder`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.AddColumnOperation> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.Builders.ColumnsBuilder.Column(System.String, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, Boolean, System.String, Boolean, System.Object, System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.String)'.

Comment: Did you write migration code manually or just ran some tool? It seems your migration code is generated for EFCore 5.0 but you are using another version.

Comment: I downgraded to EFCore 3.1 Please do me a favour by editing your answer